# How to get more and more bookmarks with twitter api v2?

Tags: javascript, twitter, bookmarks, twitter-api-v2, twitter-api-v1

I have a question about Twitter-API.
Topic endpoint="/2/users/:id/bookmarks"
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/bookmarks/api-reference/get-users-id-bookmarks

I am trying to get a user's bookmarks using the API. I have successfully retrieved quite a few at this point. The total is about 1100.
I have learned that there is a limit of 800 latest, so I am deleting them as I acquire them.

However, at some point, I started getting result_count = 0 as meta in the result when retrieved from the API, even though the bookmark is there when checked from the application.

Is there any way to work around these limitations, such as someone who has worked around a similar problem?
Thanks.

Github repository:https://github.com/BuntinJP/Twitter-API-Practice
Using twitter api client: node-twitter-api-v2
OAuth2 is succeed

To be redeleted.
Try again in a few hours.
Sending another request to the API.
Use of another client module.(Twitter TS SDK)
Testing in different languages (JS, TS, Python)